# Sum up the total amount in Abap program

Tags: abap

I'm new to Abap and  learning it from a week kindly help me with my query.

QUERY: We have vendor table and need to retrieve company code,date, fiscal year, type from a vendor table from BSAK and to sum up all the amount of one particular vendor and display it.

Need logic for sum up the total amount and display it.

Answer (score 0):

You could display your data as ALV using cl_salv_table and enable it's functions. There is one that allow user to pick a column and sum it.
There are also sorts and filters that could affect the data displayed to show only one vendor if needed.

 Check: cl_salv_table (methods: factory and display), cl_salv_functions (method set_all).